# Is BlocProvider.value redundant?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I am learning Bloc Pattern in Flutter for state management and routing. I am taking an online course. According to the course, we must provide the existing `Bloc` or `Cubit` to the newly created subtrees( In navigation parts `Navigator.push...`). I read the documentation and found out that BlocProvider.value must be used as it really said. [BlocProvider Doucmentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_bloc/latest/flutter_bloc/BlocProvider/BlocProvider.value.html)

However, I could provide the `Cubit` to newly created subtrees without using `BlocProvider.value`. What am I doing wrong? Or should I say, what am I doing right without knowing it :)?

`main.dart` routes

```
  routes: {
          "/": (context) => const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
          "/second": (context) => const SecondScreen(title: "Second screen"),
          "/third": (context) => const ThirdScreen(title: "Third screen")
        },
```

**HomeScreen**

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: BlocConsumer<CounterCubit, CounterState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          if (state.isIncremented) {
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                .showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text("Incremented")));
          } else {
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                .showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text("Decremented")));
          }
        },
        builder: (context, state) {
          return Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                const Text(
                  'You have pushed the button this many times:',
                ),
                BlocBuilder<CounterCubit, CounterState>(
                  builder: (context, state) {
                    return Text(
                      '${state.counterValue}',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
                    );
                  },
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    FloatingActionButton(
                      heroTag: UniqueKey(),
                      onPressed: () {
                        BlocProvider.of<CounterCubit>(context).decrement();
                      },
                      tooltip: 'Increment',
                      child: const Icon(Icons.text_decrease),
                    ),
                    FloatingActionButton(
                      heroTag: UniqueKey(),
                      onPressed: () {
                        BlocProvider.of<CounterCubit>(context).increment();
                      },
                      tooltip: 'Increment',
                      child: const Icon(Icons.add),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                MaterialButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second');
                  },
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: const Text("Navigate to Second Screen"),
                ),
                MaterialButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/third');
                  },
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: const Text("Navigate to Third Screen"),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**SecondScreen**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import '../cubit/counter_cubit.dart';

class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SecondScreen({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<SecondScreen> createState() => _SecondScreenState();
}

class _SecondScreenState extends State<SecondScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: BlocConsumer<CounterCubit, CounterState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          if (state.isIncremented) {
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                .showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text("Incremented")));
          } else {
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                .showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text("Decremented")));
          }
        },
        builder: (context, state) {
          return Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                const Text(
                  'You have pushed the button this many times:',
                ),
                BlocBuilder<CounterCubit, CounterState>(
                  builder: (context, state) {
                    return Text(
                      '${state.counterValue}',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
                    );
                  },
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    FloatingActionButton(
                      heroTag: UniqueKey(),
                      onPressed: () {
                        BlocProvider.of<CounterCubit>(context).decrement();
                      },
                      tooltip: 'Increment',
                      child: const Icon(Icons.text_decrease),
                    ),
                    FloatingActionButton(
                      heroTag: UniqueKey(),
                      onPressed: () {
                        BlocProvider.of<CounterCubit>(context).increment();
                      },
                      tooltip: 'Increment',
                      child: const Icon(Icons.add),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**ThirdScreen**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import '../cubit/counter_cubit.dart';

class ThirdScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ThirdScreen({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<ThirdScreen> createState() => _ThirdScreenState();
}

class _ThirdScreenState extends State<ThirdScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: BlocConsumer<CounterCubit, CounterState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          if (state.isIncremented) {
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                .showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text("Incremented")));
          } else {
            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                .showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text("Decremented")));
          }
        },
        builder: (context, state) {
          return Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                const Text(
                  'You have pushed the button this many times:',
                ),
                BlocBuilder<CounterCubit, CounterState>(
                  builder: (context, state) {
                    return Text(
                      '${state.counterValue}',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
                    );
                  },
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    FloatingActionButton(
                      heroTag: UniqueKey(),
                      onPressed: () {
                        BlocProvider.of<CounterCubit>(context).decrement();
                      },
                      tooltip: 'Increment',
                      child: const Icon(Icons.text_decrease),
                    ),
                    FloatingActionButton(
                      heroTag: UniqueKey(),
                      onPressed: () {
                        BlocProvider.of<CounterCubit>(context).increment();
                      },
                      tooltip: 'Increment',
                      child: const Icon(Icons.add),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will say that you need to understand more about how an `InheritedWidget`, `Navigator` subtrees, the `BuildContext` works in Flutter and how this relates to your topic.

in Flutter, the `MaterialApp`, is the highest component in your app, right?

so by wrapping it with a `BlocProvider`, you're offering the whole app with that bloc/cubit, so I will explain with arrow structure to make you understand what's happening.

- I will refer to "BlocProvider" as a `BlocProvider` of an example `BlocA`.
- I will refer to a Navigator first screen subtree with `SubTreeOne`.
- I will refer to a Navigator second screen subtree with `SubTreeTwo`.

when you wrap `MaterialApp` with a `BlocProvider`:

```
                                          -> SubTreOne
                                         |
BlocProvider -> MaterialApp(Navigator) ->   
                                         |
                                          -> SubTreeTwo
```

In this example, when you will try to access the `BlocA` from any of your screens (subtrees), you will not have to pass it with a `BlocProvider.value`, because the `BlocA` will always be looked up and available using the context where your widget-tree exists, so by calling `Navigator.push()`, a new subtree will be put as a child of the `Navigator`, and when trying to use the `BlocA` from that screen/route, it will lookup for it using the `BuildContext` from where it exists (in that case, the `Navigator`'s context), which means that looking up from there, it will find that `BlocA` because it is at the topmost level of your app using the `BlocProvider`.

with this approach, you guarantee that your `BlocA` will be initialized only once in your app, available in the whole app, and will not be closed in your all your app cycle, until you either close your app or close the bloc manually using the `close()` method.
so you might need this approach for handling authentication status of your users in the app, but not for using a bloc in a single screen or widget (at least, if you really care about perfermance and runtime memory of your app).

Now, let's say you have a screen that shows a simple counter that you want to re-initialize every time that screen is taken and put off again in your widget tree then you want to have the option to pass that counter value to another screen, here you will have a structure like this:

```
                         -> BlocProvider -> SubTreeOne
                         |
MaterialApp(Navigator) ->   
                         |
                          -> SubTreeTwo
```

at this example now, the `BlocA` is accesible in the `SubTreeOne` and working very fine, and each time you `Navigator.pop(context)` and `Navigator.push(...SubTreeOne())`, the bloc will be re-initialized again, as we expect, right? but when we do try to navigate to `SubTreeTwo()` now, you will notice that the `BlocA` at this point do not exists in the subtree, and you will have the most `Bloc` popular exception thrown in your app:

```
BlocProvider.of<BlocA>() called with a context that does not contain a Bloc of type BlocA.

No ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to BlocProvider.of<BlocA>().
//...
```

and this is because as I did said, when pushing a new route, a new subtree will be opened as a child of `Navigator` widget, from it's `context`, it will lookup for that `BlocA`, which will not find because on top of it, there is only a `MaterialApp` and none of the `BlocA`.

Here, you will know the value of `BlocProvider` and how it will help you for such cases, by passing the `BlocA` to it when navigating to `SubTreeTwo`, your passing that bloc to that subtree manually and make it availabele there, which fixes the issue.